# breqn causes TeX capacity exceeded when using \neq in section title

Tags: breqn

Is there a workaround this problem?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\section{$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}\neq p$ or dAlembert ode}
A

\end{document}
```

And now `lualatex foo.tex` Gives

```
....
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(./foo.out) (./foo.out)
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=50000].
\neq  ->\math_csym_Rel:Nn \neq 
                               {\not {=}}
l.7 ...ial\phi}{\partial x}\neq p$ or dAlembert ode}
                                                  
 1043 words of node memory still in use:
   14 hlist, 2 vlist, 3 rule, 3 mark, 1 disc, 1 local_par, 1 dir, 2 math, 12 gl
ue, 11 kern, 2 penalty, 26 glyph, 18 attribute, 67 glue_spec, 18 attribute_list
, 4 if_stack, 1 write, 2 pdf_dest nodes
   avail lists: 2:4,3:6,4:1,5:4,7:2,8:10,9:3
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on foo.log.
```

Replacing `\neq` by `=` it now compiles with no error.  Removing `breqn` also it compiles with no error using `\neq` in section title. So the problem is due to `breqn` being loaded.

Any workaround possible?

TL 2022.

Comment: `\texorpdfstring{$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}\neq p$}{something else}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I prefer to keep the math there as is and not replace it with text. It works for all the math in section title. It is only `\neq` that seems to cause the problem.

Comment: `breqn` is incompatible with a lot of things and thus is probably best not used.

Comment: hyperref will remove/make nonsense out of the math in the bookmarks anyway. Didn't you see (without breqn) all the warnings in the logs?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you are right, it is all garbled, I did not notice that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a minor problem: even if you disable `\neq` in the bookmarks with

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\neq{≠}}
```

you get inscrutable garbage in the bookmark anyway.

[image]

Use `\texorpdfstring`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\section{\texorpdfstring{$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}\neq p$}{∂φ/∂x≠p} or d'Alembert ode}
A

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you hope to do it “automatically”, well, good luck.