# Document hangs when compiling when loading breqn (even without using it)

Tags: tikz-pgf, breqn, braket, cryptocode

The following document hangs when compiling, seems like I can't load `breqn`, `bracket` and `cryptocode` (or is it tikz?) together… It compiles fine when I unload `\usepackage{breqn}` but I would like to use it elsewhere in the document… any idea what I did wrong or how to fix this?

```
(/nix/store/6z1x24dwqp88qh769isg4y769w47d1x2-texlive-combined-2022/share/texmf/
tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)^C  <====================== hangs here until I Ctrl-C
! Interruption.
\ket #1->\mathinner {|
                      {#1}\rangle }
l.30 }
      
? X
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}


\usepackage [
n,
lambda,
advantage,
operators,
sets,
adversary,
landau,
probability,
notions,
logic,
ff,
mm,
primitives,
events,
complexity,
asymptotics,
keys
] {cryptocode}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{breqn} % automatic line breaking: try to remove it, it will compile

\begin{document}

\pseudocodeblock{
  \text{in the main protocol} \< \sendmessage{->}{topstyle={overlay},top={$\ket{\psi^{(0)}},\ket{\psi^{(1)}}$}} \< \\
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe follow the advice from this comment https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/667604/breqn-causes-tex-capacity-exceeded-when-using-neq-in-section-title#comment1659672_667604

Comment: it's actually flexisym not breqn, I just had a quick look and it looks like a lot of work to make that work (re-write braket.sty, essentially) are you sure you want this. The breqn package is serious when it documents:  _As it pushes the envelope of what is possible within the context of LaTeX 2ε, the breqn package will tend to **break** other packages when used in combination with them, or to **fail** itself, when there are any areas of internal overlap;_

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok thanks a lot for your search. I can live without breqn, it's just a bit longer and less flexible when outputting to different width articles… But if you have better alternatives to break automatically lines, I would love to hear them!